# commuting the covariant derivative of a function

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $f$ be a smooth function such on a compact kahler manifold $(M, w)$, and the component of $w$ is denoted by $g_{ij}$, assume there is a constant $s$ such that $sf = -g^{ij}\sqrt{-1}\partial_{j}\bar\partial_{i}f$, we have:

$s \nabla_j f   = -\nabla_j \nabla_p \nabla_{\bar p} f$ suppresing the mertic.

Then how do you prove the following Bochner-Weitzenbock formula:

$(\int_{U}-\nabla_j \nabla_p \nabla_{\bar p} f \nabla_\bar j f)w^n = (\int_{U} -\nabla_{\bar p} \nabla_p \nabla_{ j} f \nabla_{\bar j} f + R^{q \bar j} \nabla_{q} f \nabla_{\bar j}f )w^n$

Thoughts: the left hand side is simply $\partial_j sf = \partial_j-g^{ik}\sqrt{-1}\partial_{j}\bar\partial_{k}f = - \partial_j g^{ik} \sqrt{-1}\partial_{j}\bar\partial_{k}f -\partial_j\sqrt{-1}\partial_{j}\bar\partial_{k}f g^{ik}$

How do you proceed?

Update:
My definition for the Ricci curvature is the following:

Lowering the index of the curvature tensor we have $R_{i \bar j k \bar l} = -\partial_{k} \partial_{l} g_{i \bar j} + g^{p \bar q}(\partial_k g_{i \bar q})(\partial_{\bar l} g_{p \bar j})$, then let $R_{i\bar j} = g^{k \bar l } R_{i \bar j k \bar l}$.

It is not obvious how to go from this definition.

Comment: Is the $\sqrt{-1}$ written in this way to not confuse with $i$ in the index?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Your identity is only using the Ricci identity; that is, the formula for how to commute derivatives in a Kähler manifold.  It requires neither integration nor the assumption $-\Delta f = sf$.

The derivation of your identity requires three observations.  First, since the connection is torsion-free, it holds that $\nabla_{\bar p}\nabla_q u = \nabla_q\nabla_{\bar p}u$ for all functions $u$.  Second, since $g$ is Kähler, it holds that
$$ \nabla_j\nabla_p\nabla_{\bar q}f = \nabla_p\nabla_j\nabla_{\bar q}f . $$
Third, by definition of the Ricci curvature,
$$ \nabla_p\nabla_{\bar p}\nabla_j f = \nabla_{\bar p}\nabla_p\nabla_j f - R_{j\bar p}\nabla_p f ; $$
here I use Einstein summation notation as in the problem statement.  Putting all of this together, we compute that
$$ -\nabla_j\nabla_p\nabla_{\bar p} f = -\nabla_p\nabla_j\nabla_{\bar p}f = -\nabla_p\nabla_{\bar p}\nabla_j f = -\nabla_{\bar p}\nabla_p\nabla_j f + R_{j\bar p}\nabla_p f . $$
Multiplying by $\nabla_{\bar j}f$ and integrating yields the display in question.  You can find proofs of these facts in Besse's book "Einstein manifolds", for example.

Comment: What do you mean by definition of the Ricci curvature? I am still very confused about the meaning of $\nabla_{j} \nabla_{p} \nabla_{\bar q} f$. Does it mean $\nabla \nabla \nabla f(\frac{\partial }{\partial z_j}, \frac{\partial }{\partial z_p}, \frac{\partial }{\partial \bar z_q})$? Can you elaborate on that a little bit?

Comment: Yes, it means $\nabla\nabla\nabla f(\partial_j,\partial_p,\partial_{\bar q})$ as you guessed.  Since $g$ is Kähler, $\nabla\nabla\nabla f(\partial_j,\partial_p,\partial_{\bar q})=\nabla\nabla\nabla f(\partial_p,\partial_j,\partial_{\bar q})$.  In general, $\nabla\nabla\nabla f(\partial_j,\partial_{\bar q},\partial_p)-\nabla\nabla\nabla f(\partial_{\bar q},\partial_j,\partial_p)=-df\bigl(R(\partial_j,\partial_{\bar q})\partial_p\bigr)$.  Contacting with $g^{j\bar q}$ gives the Ricci curvature term.  If you need me to elaborate, can you say how you define Ricci curvature?

Comment: I added my definition in the question description.